# Force two simultaneous videos with Youtube iFrame API?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, phonegap-build, youtube-iframe-api

I'm creating an app that will essentially compare two Youtube videos side by side (muted of course).

I'm more competent in html/javascript so am using Phonegap Build to put this thing together. Thanks to iOS 10.3 I can now play two html5 video elements inline no problem, which is a great start (see http://codepen.io/hay/pen/xERaVB).

The challenge now is to replace the html5 video tags with a Youtube iframe and retain the same inline, autoplay behaviour on BOTH videos at the same time.

My current code:

```js
//Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var ytPlayerVars = {
   'autoplay': 1,
   'controls': 0,
   'rel': 0,
   'modestbranding': 1,
   'showinfo': 0,
   'loop': 1
  };

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  createIframes('div_one','div_two');
}

function createIframes(divElementOne, divElementTwo){
  var iframeOne = new YT.Player(divElementOne, { // Replace div_one with an iframe
  height: '200',
  width: '200',
  videoId: 'uENITui5_jU',
  playerVars: ytPlayerVars,
  events: {
   'onReady': onIframeReady
  }
 });
  var iframeTwo = new YT.Player(divElementTwo, { // Replace div_two with an iframe
  height: '200',
  width: '200',
  videoId: 'NmS6h_fkPgk',
  playerVars: ytPlayerVars,
  events: {
   'onReady': onIframeReady
  }
 });
}

function onIframeReady(event){
  event.target.playVideo();
}
```

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_one" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
<br />
<div id="div_two" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
```

Tested and working fine on Chrome and Safari but as soon as I build it with PhoneGap and try it on iOS it's a no go.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**WARD** -> *PLZ, Answer this comment when you got the answer.*

You can try using iframes and customize it if you can't call the API more than one time.

Comment: Sorry, what's `WARD`?

Comment: League of legends... i mean if you got the answer share it.